# Show off sought value specified column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database full of data, higlighted the important ones:[image]

[image]

[image]

My task is to find those Jobs which are representing the minimum and maximum number of employed persons, **only the name of these jobs**.
Tried this unsuccessfully.

```
SELECT jobs.JOB_TITLE FROM employees
INNER JOIN jobs ON employees.JOB_ID = jobs.JOB_ID
INNER JOIN employees AS emp1 ON employees.EMPLOYEE_ID = emp1.EMPLOYEE_ID
GROUP BY jobs.JOB_ID
HAVING COUNT(MIN(emp1.EMPLOYEE_ID)) = COUNT(MIN(employees.EMPLOYEE_ID)) OR 
COUNT(MAX(emp1.EMPLOYEE_ID)) = COUNT(MAX(employees.EMPLOYEE_ID))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . One method uses the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT j.JOB_TITLE
FROM jobs j
WHERE j.job_id = (SELECT e.job_id
                  from employees e
                  GROUP BY e.job_id
                  ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC
                  LIMIT 1
                 ) OR
      j.job_id = (SELECT e.job_id
                  from employees e
                  GROUP BY e.job_id
                  ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC
                  LIMIT 1
                 ) ;
```

My preference is a window function, though:

```
select j.job_title
from jobs j join
     (select e.job_id, count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (order by count(*) asc) as seqnum_asc,
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum_desc,
      from employees e
      group by e.job_id
     ) e
     using (job_id)
where 1 in (seqnum_asc, seqnum_desc);
```

Of course, both of these only return jobs that *have* employees.  In theory, the fewest job holders could be `0`.  The second version can be tweaked to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ you can use FIRST_VALUE() window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  FIRST_VALUE(j.JOB_TITLE) OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(e.EMPLOYEE_ID)) min_job,
  FIRST_VALUE(j.JOB_TITLE) OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(e.EMPLOYEE_ID) DESC) max_job
FROM jobs j LEFT JOIN employees e 
ON e.JOB_ID = j.JOB_ID
GROUP BY j.JOB_ID, j.JOB_TITLE
```